# How to get DIVs with certain class and also without?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I've got this HTML:

```
<div class="hello top">some content</div>
<div class="hello top">some content</div>
<div class="hello">some content</div>
<div class="hello">some content</div>
<div class="hello">some content</div>
```

... and i am trying to get only those DIVs which has class "hello" but not class "top" (i want 3 last DIVs only to get).

I tried something like this but without success:

```
foreach( $html->find('div[class="hello"], div[class!="top"]') as $element ) {
  // some code...
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Code i posted didn't work. I am trying to find solution how to do that. I haven't found anything about this in documentation.

Comment: It's called simple-html-dom because it can only handle simple cases. Try phpquery or DOMXPath

Answer (score 2):

Use this method:

```
var result = $("div:not(.top)");
console.log(result);
```

//You will get only those DIV which contains class "hello".

Comment: Simple-html-dom != jQuery

Comment: How can I use jQuery on server-side? And after all, I can select all divs without class ".top" but i can't select all divs without class ".top" AND AT THE SAME TIME with class ".hello".

Answer (score 0):

According to this table ( [Supports these operators in attribute selectors](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)):

```
Filter                Description
[attribute]           Matches elements that have the specified attribute.
[!attribute]          Matches elements that don't have the specified attribute.
[attribute=value]     Matches elements that have the specified attribute with a certain value.
[attribute!=value]    Matches elements that don't have the specified attribute with a certain value.
[attribute^=value]    Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it starts with a certain value.
[attribute$=value]    Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it ends with a certain value.
[attribute*=value]    Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it contains a certain value.
```

You can use:

```
foreach( $html->find('div[class$="hello"]') as $element ) {
  // some code...
}
```

But this is not reliable solution because it matches also:

```
<div class="top hello">
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can select already your 3 latest "hello" class names.

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <?php
        $html= '
        <div class="hello top">some content</div>
        <div class="hello top">some content</div>
        <div class="hello">ee some content</div>
        <div class="hello">ee some content</div>
        <div class="hello">ee some content</div>';

            $dom = new DomDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($html);
            $dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
            $elements = $dom_xpath->query('//div[@class="hello"]');

            foreach($elements as $data){
               echo $data->getAttribute('class').'<br />';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[attribute$=value]  Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it ends with a certain value.
in your case use

```
foreach( $html->find('div[class$="hello"]') as $element ) {
  // some code...
}
```